# How to detect the jquery error for my situation described below?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, plugins, lightbox

Its Wordpress Website where i have done lots of customization as per my clients requirement i am just stuck with a problem now. I have used a jquery to tabify the UI for tabs in my sidebar section working great. I am using the below  code for tabify..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[            
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#menu').tabify();
            $('#menu2').tabify();
        }); 
        // ]]>
```

But the problem arise when i installed the "simple lightbox plugin" for the gallery section. This tabs section stops working. Not Only with this plugin, i have tried with several plugin, but i am getting the problem in this tabs. :( 
I don't have much knowledge in jquery and am helpless now. Can anyone please help me with the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install firebug and watch to see if there are any errors show.
2. Try to reverse the order in which the two are called. so call tabify after the gallery plugin

Comment: Thanks For your Reply. I had Already firebug installed, and i tried to debug using that.But, i didn't tried reversing the order of the function call. And that helped me here. Both are working fine now. Thanks a ton.  :)

Comment: No problem. I'm guessing one was conflicting with the other via the actual code or by what it was doing to manipulate the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `$(document).ready()` to handle Wordpress add-in/plug-in functionality. Wordpress has a well documented plug-in API. You basically write a server-side function in PHP, put it in the plugins folder, and tell Wordpress how and where to activate your plugin, e.g. `add_action('the_content','YourFunction');'

Depending on where you want your code to execute. Then you activate your plugin through the admin interface.

Based on your description, you want something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Tabify
 * @version 1.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Tabify
Plugin URI: http://documented.here
Description: Adds cool Tabby things
Author: hcker
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://my.website
*/

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'doTabbyStuff');

function doTabbyStuff() {
  $('#menu').tabify();
  $('#menu2').tabify();
}
?>
```

The Wordpress Plugin API is here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API